# assert, требуется фигурная скобка "}"

Tags: c++, glm

В варианте с круглыми скобками работает, а с фигурными нет.

```
assert(zAxis == vec3( 0.0,0.0,0.0 )); 

assert(zAxis == vec3{ 0.0,0.0,0.0 }); //не работает, требуется фигурная скобка "{"
```

В чем может быть причина? vec3 из GLM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В варианте с фигурными скобками препроцессор разбирает аргументы макроса до запятой как первый аргумент. Оборачивайте все выражение в скобки чтобы передать его, как единый аргумент:

```
assert((zAxis == vec3{ 0.0,0.0,0.0 }));
```